# How cobalt gold version can render the http page?

Tags: http, launch, cobalt

The cobalt version is release 11.153, I used the qa version, it can render the http page. 
But if I use the gold version, it can not render the same http page.
I also add the launch parameters --allow_http --csp_mode=disable --ignore_certificate_errors, but it still doesn't work.

So how can I change the launch parameters to launch the http page on gold version?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not to "change the launch parameters," but to change the source of the page being loaded to use https for its images. For security reasons, Cobalt gold only supports https, not http, so the images (and any other resource) referenced by the page you're loading must have an https URL.

Answer (score 0):

In Cobalt 11, gold does not respect the parameters "--csp_mode" and "--ignore_certificate_errors" in gold builds.  You will need to either use the QA version, improve the web page you are trying to access with CSP support and

Comment: For gold version， how it  can support http ?

Comment: And what could be the reason that images coming from HTTP (instead of HTTPS) are not being displayed in Gold but are displayed in QA.

Comment: The following CSP header is as bellow:                                                     
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://www.googleapis.com https://www.googleapis.com:*; 
            style-src 'self';
            img-src *;            
            script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'">

Comment: As Andrew said, 'gold' build does not support http connection on purpose for the security reasons. Are you loaing an image from http url while the page itself is https?

Comment: Yes, the page is local, we can visit it by file:///, but for the page's image, it is a http url, so Cobalt can support and display the image. For qa version, it can display the image, but for gold, it can't display the image.

Comment: I try to remove the parameter "COBALT_FORCE_HTTPS" and "COBALT_FORCE_CSP"at https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/19.lts.stable/src/cobalt/build/config/BUILD.gn#157, but it doesn't work, so how can I config it to support http ?